# Given acceleration from a accelerometer, how to modelize the position in space of the module?

Tags: java, modeling, java-3d, orbital-mechanics, grovepi+

I am getting the 3dimensional values of a grove pi module, 
**acc_vector = (accX, accY, accZ)**
 each 100 milliseconds .
What I want is, using java, diplaying the movement that I make with the module...but my problem is not how to display it :p

For this I need to compute the value of the position 
**position_vector = (x,y,z)**
corresponding to the acceleration values. But I have no clue about how to do it.

Here is what I've tried, but it always gives odd results (initial position, speed and acceleration are (0,0,0) ):

- `position_vector  = 0.5f*acc_vector*t;`
- `position_vector += acc_vector;`
- `position_vector  = acc_vector*(t-t_just_before);`

Comment: Do you understand the physics behind this? The relationship between acceleration, velocity, and position?

Comment: Yup, I guess I understand them.But I cannot understand how to find the position values when the acceleration is not a proper function we can derivate.Here the acceleration values are just punctual values . If you have some solutions or hints, I would be really happy....

Comment: And even if you think I don't understand something, could you maybe help me?

Comment: What type is `position_vector`? Is it a `double[]`? A `javax.vecmath.Vector3d`?

Comment: all my vectors are tables: float[3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on how you want to interpolate the acceleration. The easiest (but likely least accurate) would be to assume constant acceleration between samples. In that situation, your code for the `x`component should resemble

```
position[0] += velocity[0] * timeStep + 0.5 * acceleration[0] * timeStep * timeStep;
velocity[0] += acceleration[0] * timeStep;
```

You would have to do the same for the `y` and `z` components.

To get more accurate results, you may need more sophisticated techniques. You can look up numerical methods such as [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

Comment: Runge-Kutta or single-step methods will not help much if the acceleration is only provided at regular sample points. You would need to be able to evaluate the acceleration at (relatively) arbitrary states. What you can use to get higher error orders are explicit **multi-step methods** ([Adams–Bashforth methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method#Adams.E2.80.93Bashforth_methods)).